# Upload videos to website from iPhone application

Tags: iphone, video, upload

I am developing an application in iPhone. This applications also have its own website. 
The iPhone application requires uploading videos from iPhone to the website. I don't know how 
to do this task. Please suggest me a coding or any guide to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSURL *urlvideo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];


urlvideo contains the URL of that video file that has to be uploaded. Then convert the url into NSString type because setFile method requires NSString as a parameter

NSString *urlString=[urlvideo path];

NSLog(@"urlString=%@",urlString);
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"path of server"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setFile:urlString forKey:@"key foruploadingFile"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];
NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %i",[request responseStatusCode]);
NSLog(@"responseStatusCode %@",[request responseString]);
```